# Single Sign-On between 2 different platforms but on the same domain

Tags: oracle, security, sharepoint, single-sign-on

I'm in the process of rearranging our web-based systems, so that users will be able to log on to our systems through a Sharepoint front-end. Our single sign-on server is an Oracle SSO server that authenticates against the same domain as the sharepoint server does, but these two are currently 2 separate logins.

**What I'm looking for is to configure this scenario:** 
A user logs in to the Sharepoint site, authenticating agains Active Directory through the TMG. This gives the user access to the sharepoint site, and this is all standard OOTB functionality. Then the user should be able to navigate into our other systems without a re-login (because the SSO configured for external authentication with the same AD, and therefore uses the same userbase).

So basically the users currently have to login twice with the same domain\user + password. I would like the SSO server to be able to read the cookie that was established in the first login, and use that instead of presenting the SSO login screen all over again.

Is it possible to share such a cookie between 2 different platforms on the same domain?

I have implemented a kerberos "Zero-sign-on" approach for the Oracle SSO server, but this only works as long as the user comes from a computer inside our domain. When the user logs on from the outside world (www) he will be prompted to login to sharepoint first, and then to the Oracle SSO.

I basically need the Oracle SSO Cookie to somehow read the Sharepoint Cookie that was established. Does this make sense?

Comment: Sign is removed, Please refer the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures